# Insert into a table selecting data from a sub query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, join

I would like to insert a few data into a table selecting data from a subquery having multiple joins.

I tried the following way:

```
insert into mytable (columns) 
select * from 
 (select columns 
  from tableA 
  UNION ALL 
  select columns from tableB 
  UNION ALL 
  select columns from tableC)
```

Can you please suggest me a way out, since I am getting the following error while executing the above query.

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: give the alias to your subquery, i.e. ")t" instead of ")" at the end of youe query

Comment: @sepupic, thanks for the help. It really worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add some alias:

```
insert into mytable (columns) 
select t.* from (
    select columns from tableA 
    UNION ALL
    select columns from tableB
    UNION ALL
    select columns from tableC
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `select * from (` and trailing `)` from your query - it is excessive.

```
insert into mytable (columns) 
select columns from tableA 
UNION ALL 
select columns from tableB 
UNION ALL 
select columns from tableC
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4d5c42f7e77ffebdee879f3e99968d97)